# More keys pressed in C# Game

Tags: c#

I made a game named "[Spaceship Invaders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Invaders)" in C#. For the ship movements, i wrote some code (at `KeyDown` Form event) but, it not so efficient.

For example: If I press Left key and Up key, at the same time, and I keep pressing, the KeyDown event will take the first key pressed(it's impossible to press 2 keys at the same time).

```
switch (e.KeyCode)
{
    case Keys.Left:
        if(SHIP.Location.X - move_LEFT >= 0)
            SHIP.Location = new Point(SHIP.Location.X - move_LEFT, SHIP.Location.Y);
        if (using_mouse)
            Cursor.Position = SHIP.Location;
        break;

    case Keys.Up:
        if(SHIP.Location.Y - move_UP >= 0)
            SHIP.Location = new Point(SHIP.Location.X, SHIP.Location.Y - move_UP);
        if (using_mouse)
            Cursor.Position = SHIP.Location;
        break;
}
```

Where move_UP and move_Left are variables int.

```
protected int move_LEFT = 40;
protected int move_UP = 40;
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: You should probably look at a game library like DirectX or XNA.

Comment: Whilst you're working on this, be aware that [most keyboards are physically incapable](http://pcbheaven.com/wikipages/How_Key_Matrices_Works/) of registering key combinations of certain keys.

Comment: Can you tell me how to make with DirectX, please?

Comment: @VoiculescuCristianConstantin Google it. You'll find something.